# Theorem failure if we restricted our world of numbers to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

Why would the following theorems fail if we restricted our world of numbers to $\mathbb{Q}$?

1) A sequence is convergent if and only if it is Cauchy

2) All bounded monotone sequences converge

Comment: Consider an increasing sequence of rationals that converges to $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 3):

Take the sequence $3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415, 3.14159...$ This is Cauchy, bounded, and monotone, but it does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}$, since $\pi$ is not rational.

Comment: Crucially here, "converges" means "converges in $\mathbb{Q})"

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $(s_n) = 1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n^2}$. This sequence is bounded, monotone increasing, and Cauchy, but it does not converge in $\mathbb Q$ since its limit $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ does not exist in $\mathbb Q$. However, it converges in $\mathbb R$ since its limit exists in $\mathbb R$.

Both theorems in your question rely on the completeness axiom, which states that *every nonempty subset* $S$ *of* $\mathbb R$ *that is bounded above has a least upper bound. In other words,* $\sup S$ *exists and is a real number.*